# Trouble constructing intersection graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics

After looking at the answer in the book, I still cannot figure out how to construct an intersection graph even though I know each meaning of each term.

Given Question:

The intersection graph of a collection of sets $A_1$, $A_2$,..., $A_n$ is
the graph that has a vertex for each of these sets and has an edge connecting
the vertices representing two sets if these sets have a nonempty intersection.
Construct the intersection graph of these collections of sets.

a) $A_1$ = {0,2,4,6,8}, $A_2$ = {0,1,2,3,4}, $A_3$ = {1,3,5,7,9}, $A_4$ = {5,6,7,8,9},
$A_5$ = {0,1,8,9}

What I know:

$A_1$ is the the set denoted as a vertex of the graph

What I do not understand:

What do the numbers mean inside the set of $A_1$,...,$A_n$?

I know the graph has 5 vertices because there are 5 listed sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers $0,2,4,6,8$ in $A_1 = \{0,2,4,6,8\}$ are just the *elements* of the set $A_1$. So you have, for instance, $A_1\cap A_2=\{0,2,4\}$, and your intersection graph will contain the edge between $A_1$ and $A_2$. Similarly, $A_1\cap A_3=\varnothing$, and there will be no edge between $A_1$ and $A_3$, and so on.

Comment: So there is no edge between $A_1$ and $A_3$ because they do not share the same element in their set. Am I correct to say that given your response?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by 'sharing the same element in their set'. I would rather say that $A_1$ and $A_3$ have no common element, or, more formally, that *they have empty intersection*.

Answer (score 0):

A1 = {0,2,4,6,8}, A2 = {0,1,2,3,4}, A3 = {1,3,5,7,9}, A4 = {5,6,7,8,9}, A5 = {0,1,8,9}

Find the intersections between each set:

A1 ∩ A2 = 0,2,4

A1 ∩ A3 = ∅

A1 ∩ A4 = 6,8

A1 ∩ A5 = 0,8

A2 ∩ A3 = 1,3

A2 ∩ A4 = ∅

A2 ∩ A5 = 0,1

A3 ∩ A4 = 7

A3 ∩ A5 = 1,9

A4 ∩ A5 = 8,9

If there is an intersection the 2 sets are connected by an edge. If there are no values in the intersection ∅, then there is no edge.